# Can I delete particular file from firefox cache?

Tags: firefox, caching, browser-cache, cache-control

I am developing an ASP.net application.

Where I have to frequently update my CSS file. I don't want to update document frequency setting in from `about:config` in Firefox. I want to let it default.

I use Firefox as an Ideal browser. If I just update my CSS file, I have to clear whole cache of Firefox.

I want to delete particular file from Firefox cache. Is this possible in Firefox. I can delete particular cookie in Firefox. Can't I delete particular file from Firefox cache?

If It is not possible then please tell me how can I make my CSS file in the way that it should be always checked (and only load if modified) for newer version. I do not want to change Firefox settings in any case.

Comment: you mean with code or using firefox?

Comment: So the answer is no then? The accepted answer won't work for iframes, and none of the answers actually answer the question.

Comment: Yes the answer is NO till now. @chiliNUT

Comment: what is different now?

Comment: Any update on this topic in 2022?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I remember correctly, the keycombination CTRL + F5 cleats the cache and the css-files have to be reloaded.

Comment: You just saved me from getting a heart attack with some .js files. Thanks! This solutions works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible via a few lines of script (to be run on the Browser Console, `Ctrl+Shift+J`):

```js
// load the disk cache
var cacheservice = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/netwerk/cache-storage-service;1"]
    .getService(Components.interfaces.nsICacheStorageService);
var {LoadContextInfo} = Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/LoadContextInfo.jsm",{})
var hdcache = cacheservice.diskCacheStorage(LoadContextInfo.default, true);
    
// compose the URL and submit it for dooming
var uri = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"]
    .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIIOService).newURI(prompt("Enter the URL to kick out:"), null, null);
hdcache.asyncDoomURI(uri, null, null);
```

As long as you know the absolute URL of the CSS file, you could replace `prompt("Enter the URL to kick out:")` with the URL.

Adapted from [DoomEntry.js](https://github.com/janakaud/js-on-firefox/blob/master/console/DoomEntry.js), confirmed to work on latest Firefox (Quantum) as well.

Comment: EDIT: since FF 60, lines 2-3 should be replaced with `var hdcache = cacheservice.diskCacheStorage(Services.loadContextInfo.default, true);`; kudos to https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1417937. (For some reason I'm not allowed to edit my original answer.)

Comment: @Noitidart yup, unfortunately :( but the old APIs are still supported (at least thus far)

Comment: I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Components.classes is undefined` in FF v98.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

Using an [ETag](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee619764%28WS.10%29.aspx) would be a good option.  By setting the Max-Age Header in HTTP responses, you can allow the client to cache the resource for a limited time.  After that time, the client will make a conditional GET request to the server.  If the ETag (stored in the If-None-Match header) in the request doesn't match the ETag on the server, the modified resource will be sent down to the client.  Otherwise the server responds with HTTP 304 Not Modified and the client can cache the content for a limited time again.  This approach can be used for particular files or for directories.

Comment: I upped your answer. But I think these can be configured at IIS level, and in my case (shared hosting), I do not have access to IIS configurations. Is there an alternate for the same.

Answer (score 1):

Add a last update time stamp to the linked file.
This is what it would look like in php

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?lu=<?php echo filectime('css/style.css') ?>" />
```

This will cause the browser to reload the file only when the file is updated.