# Find and remove file from cache

Tags: firefox-addon

I have this css which applies `background-image: path/to/desktop/build1.png`.

So whatever is `build1.png` on desktop will be the background image. However, in my addon, after I dynamically delete build1.png and replace it with another image that I rename build1.png, the background-image does not update. I tried ctrl+f5 and it didn't work. So I'm thinking after I dynamically replace the image on the desktop I should delete it from cache.

Test case, copy paste to scratchpad with environment browser and hit run, it opens a new tab with a gui for the test case. Hit "Release Img" then hit "applyCss" then hit "Aurora Img" and watch how the background of the div doesn't change.

Here is youtube video demo of this testcase demo'ing the issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mbGJxHtstrw

```
var tab = gBrowser.loadOneTab('data:text/html,<div class="profilist-icon-build-1">backround of this span is of icon on desktop</div><input type="button" value="applyCss"><input type="button" value="removeCss"> Change File on Desktop to: <input type="button" value="Release Img"><input type="button" value="Beta Img"><input type="button" value="Aurora Img"><input type="button" value="Nightly Img">', {inBackground:false});
//start - listen for loadOneTab to finish loading per https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/0f076070bc77abd5e406
var mobs = new window.MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {          
    if (mutation.attributeName == 'progress' && tab.getAttribute('progress') == '') {
      //alert('tab done loading');
      init();
      mobs.disconnect();
    }

  });
});
mobs.observe(tab, {attributes: true});
//end - listen for loadOneTab to finish loading per https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/0f076070bc77abd5e406
function init() {
  //run on load of the loadOneTab
  var win = tab.linkedBrowser.contentWindow;
  var doc = win.document;

  var btns = doc.querySelectorAll('input[type=button]');
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(btns, function(b) {
    b.addEventListener('click', handleBtnClick, false);
  });

}

Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/osfile.jsm');
var sss = Cc['@mozilla.org/content/style-sheet-service;1'].getService(Ci.nsIStyleSheetService);
var cssBuildIconsStr = '.profilist-icon-build-1 { background-image: url("' + OS.Path.toFileURI(OS.Path.join(OS.Constants.Path.desktopDir, 'build1.png')) + '"); ';
var newURIParam = {
  aURL: 'data:text/css,' + encodeURIComponent(cssBuildIconsStr),
  aOriginCharset: null,
  aBaseURI: null
};
var cssBuildIconsURI = Services.io.newURI(newURIParam.aURL, newURIParam.aOriginCharset, newURIParam.aBaseURI);

function handleBtnClick(e) {
  var targ = e.target;
  var doc = e.target.ownerDocument;
  var win = doc.defaultView;
  switch(targ.value) {
    case 'applyCss':
      if (sss.sheetRegistered(cssBuildIconsURI, sss.AUTHOR_SHEET)) {
        win.alert('ERROR: Sheet is already registered! Will not re-register...');
      } else {
       sss.loadAndRegisterSheet(cssBuildIconsURI, sss.AUTHOR_SHEET);
       win.alert('REGISTERED')
      }
      break;
    case 'removeCss':
      if (sss.sheetRegistered(cssBuildIconsURI, sss.AUTHOR_SHEET)) {
        sss.unregisterSheet(cssBuildIconsURI, sss.AUTHOR_SHEET);
        win.alert('UNregged');
      } else {
        win.alert('ERROR: Sheet is not registered! Nothing to unregister...');
      }
      break;
    case 'Release Img':
      xhr('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Noitidart/Profilist/%2321/bullet_release.png', function(d){saveToDiskAsBuild1(d, win)});
      break;
    case 'Beta Img':
      xhr('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Noitidart/Profilist/%2321/bullet_beta.png', function(d){saveToDiskAsBuild1(d, win)});
      break;
    case 'Aurora Img':
      xhr('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Noitidart/Profilist/%2321/bullet_aurora.png', function(d){saveToDiskAsBuild1(d, win)});
      break;
    case 'Nightly Img':
      xhr('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Noitidart/Profilist/%2321/bullet_nightly.png', function(d){saveToDiskAsBuild1(d, win)});
      break;
    default:
      win.alert('unknown button clicked, value = "' + targ.value + '"');
  }
}

function xhr(url, cb) {
    let xhr = Cc["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIXMLHttpRequest);

    let handler = ev => {
        evf(m => xhr.removeEventListener(m, handler, !1));
        switch (ev.type) {
            case 'load':
                if (xhr.status == 200) {
                    cb(xhr.response);
                    break;
                }
            default:
                Services.prompt.alert(null, 'XHR Error', 'Error Fetching Package: ' + xhr.statusText + ' [' + ev.type + ':' + xhr.status + ']');
                break;
        }
    };

    let evf = f => ['load', 'error', 'abort'].forEach(f);
    evf(m => xhr.addEventListener(m, handler, false));

    xhr.mozBackgroundRequest = true;
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.channel.loadFlags |= Ci.nsIRequest.LOAD_ANONYMOUS | Ci.nsIRequest.LOAD_BYPASS_CACHE | Ci.nsIRequest.INHIBIT_PERSISTENT_CACHING;
    xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer"; //dont set it, so it returns string, you dont want arraybuffer. you only want this if your url is to a zip file or some file you want to download and make a nsIArrayBufferInputStream out of it or something
    xhr.send(null);
}

function saveToDiskAsBuild1(data, win) {
          var file = OS.Path.join(OS.Constants.Path.desktopDir, 'build1.png');
          var promised = OS.File.writeAtomic(file, new Uint8Array(data));
          promised.then(
              function() {
                  win.alert('succesfully saved image to desktop')
              },
              function(ex) {
                   win.alert('FAILED in saving image to desktop')
              }
          );
}
```

Comment: Weird. I uninstall and reinstall addon or restart browser and it seems to reflect changed image. However if i hit F5 or Ctrl+F5 it wont update.

Comment: It would be a surprise (and a serious performance hit) if `file:` resources were cached at disk storage. What I find interesting is that it looks like they are not memory-cached either.

Comment: Thanks man for the comment I'll write a testcase for this today :)

Comment: I'm really curious, can you confirm that `file:` resources are not cached in memory? Check `about:cache`

Comment: Hey man I added a test case. I'm not so good with about:cache I tried to confirm but Im not sure :(

Comment: Here is a screencast demo'ing the issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mbGJxHtstrw

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210786/can-i-delete-particular-file-from-firefox-cache#48353595) if you want to delete the entry from the cache

Comment: Thank you @Janaka!