# How to find specific cache entries in firefox and turn them into a File or Blob object?

Tags: javascript, firefox, caching, firefox-addon

I have the following scenario:

A user can paste html content in a wysiwyg editor. When that pasted content contains images which are hosted on other domains, I want these to be uploaded to my server. Right now the only way of doing that is manually downloading via "save image as..." context menu, then uploading the image to the server via a form and updating the images in the editor.

I have to solve this client side.

I'm working on a firefox addon that can automate the process. Of course I could download these images, store them on the harddrive and then upload them with FormData or better the pupload , but this seems clumsy as since the content is displayed in the browser, it must be downloaded already and reside somewhere in memory. I would like to grab the image files from memory and tell firefox to upload them (being able to make a Blob of them would suffice it seems).

However, I'm getting hopelessly lost in the API documentation for several different Caching systems on MDN and fail to find any example code of how to use them. I checked code of other addons that access the cache, but most is uncommented and still quite cryptic.

Can you point me to some sample code of what the recommended way would be to achieve this? The best possible solution would be if I can request the particular url from firefox so I can use it in FormData, and if it isn't in the cache firefox downloads to memory, but if it's already there I just get it directly.

Comment: This user on mozillazine,Githlar, has lots of experience with cache, if i ever had any questions cache related he told me to run it by him. Post up this topic on mzine and send the guy a message, this is an awesome question and i would like to see an answer :)

Comment: Thanks for your hint, I'm behind a tor firewall, and I can't access the mozilla zine forums because it says ip banned... Do you have any means of contacting this user?

Comment: Hello nus, I've got a few questions: your WYSIWYG editor is like a webapp, correct? If that's the case, you shouldn't need an addon to do this, just have some server-side script download the images, put them somewhere and replace all instances of the remote URL with the local URL. However, if you must use an extension... well, I'm still trying to think this one through. I can tell you it will be fairly easy compared to what I was trying to do. But I do agree, the Mozilla docs of Cache v2 are atrocious.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reacting. I have to do this client side. The server is not allowed to connect out for security reasons. For now I have used a workaround by using Download.jsm to just download them in a temporary directory, to then upload them by creating a File object. I would just like to avoid storing that extra copy on the users hard drive as they are already in memory, and it means guaranteeing proper cleanup in all circumstances.

Comment: I understand. Personally, I don't think it's the best way to go about it. Most people probably aren't going to want to install an extra addon just to get functionality that should be there without it. However, given the extenuating circumstances, I can understand the approach and I'll sure help you out. Give me a couple hours to review my code that used the cache so I can give you a good solution =).

Comment: Sorry it took so long to get back to you. I hope you find my long-awaited answer satisfactory.

Comment: Link to Githalrs topic on mozillazine as reference: [mozillaZine :: HTTP Cache v2 Woes](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=2885519)

Answer (score 5):

The master documentation for Mozilla's version 2 HTTP Cache is located [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_Cache). Aside from the blurbs on this page, the only way I was able to make sense of this new scheme is by looking at the actual code for each object and back-referencing almost everything. Even though I wasn't able to get a 100% clear picture of what exactly was going on, I figured out enough to get it working. In my opinion, Mozilla should have taken the time to create some simple-terms documentation before they went ahead an pushed out the new API. But, we get what they give us I suppose.

On to your problem. We're assuming that the users who want to upload an image already have this image saved in their cache somewhere. In order to be able to pull it out of the user's cache for upload, you must first be able to determine the URI of the image before it can be pulled explicitly from the cache. For the sake of brevity, I'm going to assume that you already have this part figured out.

An important thing to note about the new HTTP Cache is that although it's all based off callbacks, there can still only ever be a single writing process. While in your example it may not be necessary to write to the descriptor, you should still request write access since that will prevent any other processes (i.e. the browser) from altering/deleting the data until you are done with it. Another side note and a source of a lot of pain for me was the fact that requesting a cache entry from the memory cache will **ALWAYS** created a new entry, overwriting any pre-existing entries. You shouldn't need this, but if it is necessary, you can access the memory cache from the disk (the disk cache is physical disk+memory cache -- Mozilla logic) cache without that side effect.

Once the URI is in hand, you can then make a request to pull it out of the cache. The new caching system is based completely on callbacks. There is one key object that we will need in order to be able to fetch the cache entry's data -- [nsICacheEntryOpenCallback](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/cache2/nsICacheEntryOpenCallback.idl). This is a user-defined object that handles the response after a cache entry is requested. It must have two member functions: onCacheEntryCheck(entry, appcache) and onCacheEntryAvilable(descriptor, isnew, appcache, status).

Here is a cut-down example from my code of such an object:

```
var cacheWaiter = {
  //This function essentially tells the cache service whether or not we want
  //this cache descriptor. If ENTRY_WANTED is returned, the cache descriptor is
  //passed to onCacheEntryAvailable()
  onCacheEntryCheck: function( descriptor, appcache )
  {
    //First, we want to be sure the cache entry is not currently being written
    //so that we can be sure that the file is complete when we go to open it.
    //If predictedDataSize > dataSize, chances are it's still in the process of
    //being cached and we won't be able to get an exclusive lock on it and it
    //will be incomplete, so we don't want it right now.
    try{
      if( descriptor.dataSize < descriptor.predictedDataSize )
        //This tells the nsICacheService to call this function again once the
        //currently writing process is done writing the cache entry.
        return Components.interfaces.nsICacheEntryOpenCallback.RECHECK_AFTER_WRITE_FINISHED;
    }
    catch(e){
      //Also return the same value for any other error
      return Components.interfaces.nsICacheEntryOpenCallback.RECHECK_AFTER_WRITE_FINISHED;
    }
    //If no exceptions occurred and predictedDataSize == dataSize, tell the
    //nsICacheService to pass the descriptor to this.onCacheEntryAvailable()
    return Components.interfaces.nsICacheEntryOpenCallback.ENTRY_WANTED;
  }

  //Once we are certain we want to use this descriptor (i.e. it is done
  //downloading and we want to read it), it gets passed to this function
  //where we can do what we wish with it.
  //At this point we will have full control of the descriptor until this
  //function exits (or, I believe that's how it works)
  onCacheEntryAvailable: function( descriptor, isnew, appcache, status )
  {
    //In this function, you can do your cache descriptor reads and store
    //it in a Blob() for upload. I haven't actually tested the code I put
    //here, modifications may be needed.
    var cacheentryinputstream = descriptor.openInputStream(0);
    var blobarray = new Array(0);
    var buffer = new Array(1024);      

    for( var i = descriptor.dataSize; i == 0; i -= 1024)
    {
      var chunksize = 1024;
      if( i < 0 )
        chunksize = 1024 + i;
      try{
        cacheentryinputstream.read( buffer, chunksize );
      }
      catch(e){
        //Nasty NS_ERROR_WOULD_BLOCK exceptions seem to happen to me
        //frequently. The Mozilla guys don't provide a way around this,
        //since they want a responsive UI at all costs. So, just keep
        //trying until it succeeds.
        i += 1024;
        continue;
      }
      for( var j = 0; j < chunksize; j++ )
      {
        blobarray.push(buffer.charAt(j));
      }
      if( i < 0 )
        i = 0 //Set i == 0 to signal loop break
    }
  }
  var theblob = new Blob(blobarray);
  //Do an AJAX POST request here.
}
```

Now that the callback object is set up, we can actually do some requests for cache descriptors. Try something like this:

```
var theuri = "http://www.example.com/image.jpg";

//Load the cache service
var cacheservice = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/netwerk/cache-storage-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsICacheStorageService)

//Select the default disk cache.
var hdcache = cacheservice.diskCacheStorage(Services.loadContextInfo.default, true);

//Request a cache entry for the URI. OPEN_NORMALLY requests write access.
hdcache.asyncOpenURI(ioservice.newURI(theuri, null, null), "", hdcache.OPEN_NORMALLY, cacheWaiter);
```

As far as actually getting the URI, you could provide a window for a user to drag-and-drop an image into or perhaps just paste the URL of the image into. Then, you could do an AJAX request to fetch the image (in the case that the user hasn't actually visited the image for some reason, it would then be cached). You could then use that URL to then fetch the cache entry for upload. As an aesthetic touch, you could even show a preview of the image but that's a bit out of scope of the question.

If you need any more clarifications, please feel free to ask!

Comment: Thank you so much. This is an incredible answer. I think it will save me several days of work and probably others too. Yes, I have the urls, which I grab from tinymce after a paste event. Right now I have implemented a workaround which just downloads them to a temp folder and uploads them afterwards with the File API. I can even pass the File objects to plupload, so it just integrates into the site nicely. I suppose I will still need that just in case the cache entry doesn't exist, but I will try to save it in the cache rather than in a temp directory.

Comment: When I come round to integrating that all I will use the code you posted to make a facade class that will hide the mozilla api from my application code. Basically, to my application I will want to make it look like it tells firefox: upload the file at this remote location to this server. (I think that some browsers allow a user to past a url into the html file input element, but firefox does not if I'm not mistaking). Maybe I'll make some javascript library which allows just that. Then for addons it's just a matter of setting the value of the file input.

Comment: I'm very busy, so it will be a few weeks before I come back to this, but when I understand things better I will also try to improve the mdn documentation where it is cryptic. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: An absolutely amazing answer. Thank you Githlar!! @nus you should mark this as accepted!! This is really good stuff! You can always ask questions after you get around to testing it in the comments, Gith wont run away once you mark his solution as accepted haha awesome fellow! thanks Gith!

Comment: Thanks for the positive feedback nus. I would have updated the documentation long ago with my findings, but I don't have an account to do so nor do I know a way of creating one. When I first started delving into the new cache system it seemed like that documentation was written for developers by developers (actual Firefox developers, not addon developers). Luckily, I have experience in other programming languages so I was able to figure it out enough to use it but I doubt others were so lucky.

Comment: do you have a github account? Because you can login to mdn using github directly, which I found quite convenient...

Comment: @Githlar is it possible to remove an entry for cache, so forcing firefox to download it again on next time it is requested? here is my bugzilla topic with full fledged copy paste example: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1059155 and here is my corresponding topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25466415/find-and-remove-file-from-cache

Comment: Reminder to self: To fix this example `Simple javascript error. nsIInputStream.read() requires an array to read into, not an undefined variable. Try declaring with "var buffer[1024]". That read loop doesn't look right either, I think it will skip the last chunk of the file. The for loop condition might need to be "i > 0".` from: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?p=14169473#p14169473

Comment: Since FF60, line 3 has to be removed (as per [this change](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1417937)) and line 4 (`hdcache` declaration) has to be replaced with `var hdcache = cacheservice.diskCacheStorage(Services.loadContextInfo.default, true);`

Comment: @Noitidart [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210786/can-i-delete-particular-file-from-firefox-cache#48353595) might be useful