# Accessing the cache with a Firefox addon

Tags: javascript, firefox, caching, firefox-addon

I am working on a Firefox addon which collects info on .js and .css files. I would like to build a function to which I would pass a URL and the function then checks if this file is in Firefox's cache, it's size, if it was gzipped, when the caching expires and ideally also the response headers and the content itself. Can somebody help me? I have tried reading the documentation, but it means nothing to me: code is something I can understand better.

Comment: Cache access is missing a lot of documentation but @Githlar is an expert on it and if you need more help on it he would gladly help you out. But see these topics you may not need to reach out to him: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28182069/1828637 || http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=2885519