# nsICacheService doesn't work in Firefox 38

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I use

```
Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/cache-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsICacheService);
```

to manipulate http cache when developing Firefox extension.

But after I upgrade to Firefox 38 esr, this interface throws error when calling its function

```
[Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004001 (NS_ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED) [nsICacheService.visitEntries]" nsresult: "0x80004001 (NS_ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED)"
```

And I didn't find it obsolete in MDN, so anyone knows why? Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is very cool work, the cache stuff isn't documented so well on MDN, did you see this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27842615/how-to-find-specific-cache-entries-in-firefox-and-turn-them-into-a-file-or-blob its not exactly your issue but its cache work too. Can you please link to your open source code, I am very curious to learn from it how to use nsICacheService

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://code.metager.de/source/xref/mozilla/firefox/netwerk/cache/nsICacheService.idl

This looks like a hint
* @throws NS_ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED when the cache v2 is prefered to use.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=913807

I’m thinking that all we need to do is change 1 to 2 in this line in the

var cacheService = cc["@mozilla.org/network/cache-service;1"]
                .getService(ci.nsICacheService);

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code and it throws: (copy paste run in scratcpad in browser environment - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oo4STWceGTM )

```
var cacheService = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/cache-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsICacheService);
console.log('cacheService:', cacheService);

function CacheVisitor(){}

CacheVisitor.prototype = {
    QueryInterface : function(iid)
    {
        if (iid.equals(Ci.nsICacheVisitor))
            return this;
        throw Components.results.NS_NOINTERFACE;
    },

    visitDevice : function(deviceID, deviceInfo)
    {
        console.log("[visiting device (deviceID = ", deviceID ,", description = ", deviceInfo.description ,")]");
        return true;
    },

    visitEntry : function(deviceID, entryInfo)
    {
        console.log("[visiting entry (clientID = ", entryInfo.clientID, "key = ", entryInfo.key, ")]");
        return true;
    }
};
var visitor = new CacheVisitor();
cacheService.visitEntries(visitor); // throws on this line here!!!
```

It throws on line `cacheService.visitEntries(visitor); // throws on this line here!!!` it throws this:

```
/*
Exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004001 (NS_ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED) [nsICacheService.visitEntries]"  nsresult: "0x80004001 (NS_ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED)"  location: "JS frame :: Scratchpad/1 :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 27"  data: no]
*/
```

This is the same issue you're having it looks like. Can you verify, I dont see reproducible code from you.

Comment: yes, just like your code, when calling cacheService.visitEntries(), it throws error.

Comment: from MozillaZine, they tell me nsICacheService is marked for removal. details: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=2940611

Comment: In the code above, visitEntries() isn't defined, only visitEntry() is that perhaps the problem?

Comment: Thanks @Githlar I'm not sure but its actually been deprecated in favor of the new caching system as linked by that mozillazine topic: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_Cache